# Operand data type varchar is invalid for divide operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just started using SQL and I have a pretty basic question:

I'm tried dividing 2 columns (amount/rate) - I converted them from 'money' to 'INT' but when I tried executing it gave me this error:

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for divide operator.

This is the query I typed:

```
select referenceid, 
       CONVERT(decimal(15,3), sellamount) as 'amount', 
       CONVERT(decimal(15,3), rateactual) as 'Rate',
       CONVERT(decimal(15,3), 'amount' / 'rate') as 'local amount'
FROM currencyfxconversions
```

Can someone help me understand what I did wrong?

Comment: `'Rate'` is in `varchar` type..You may need to use `convert(decimal(15,3),'amount' / convert(decimal(15,3), rateactual)` instead of `convert(decimal(15,3),'amount' / 'rate')`.

Comment: sql-server and MySql are two different products.

Comment: What are you trying to do? 'rate' is a string containing the characters 'r', 'a', 't', and 'e'. You cannot devide the string 'amount' by the string 'rate'. If you want to use alias names, use the standard double quotes, e.g. "rate" - single quotes are for string literals. But then: you cannot use the alias name in the same select clause where you define it, because there is no order in which the values are evaluated (i.e. the line `as "local amount"` may be executed before the line `as "amount"`).

Comment: Then, what type are `sellamount` and `rateactual`? Aren't they already numeric? Then `CONVERT` does about nothing. Maybe you want to make them *strings* in a certain format (e.g. 3 decimal places) for display instead? Then use the appropriate format function (which is probably different in MySQL and SQL Server).

Comment: Thank you guys, that was very helpful! so I entered the below query and it worked! select referenceid, 
       CONVERT(decimal(15,3), sellamount) as 'amount', 
       convert(decimal(15,3), rateactual) as 'Rate',
       (convert(decimal(15,3), sellamount) / convert(decimal(15,3), rateactual))
FROM currencyfxconversions.

Comment: The question is.. why do I need to convert twice? after I set the "amount" and "rate" as numbers, why do I need to set it again when I divide the two? also, after I name a column, can't I refer to everything as the name I gave it? Apologies for the newbies questions, I really just started working with it. thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT referenceid
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), sellamount) AS 'amount'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), rateactual) AS 'Rate'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), sellamount) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), rateactual))) AS 'local amount'
FROM currencyfxconversions
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried:  (convert(decimal(15,3), sellamount) / convert(decimal(15,3), rateactual)) and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're using a column that you use in the same context. You can't use am alias as a table column in the select context. You must repeat the last alias queries, as follows:

```
SELECT referenceid
,CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), sellamount) AS 'amount'
,CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), rateactual) AS 'Rate'
,CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), sellamount) / convert(DECIMAL(15, 3), rateactual))) AS 'local amount'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original query,

```
convert(decimal(15,3),'amount' / 'rate')
```

Must be replaced with:

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(decimal(15,3), sellamount) / CONVERT(decimal(15,3), rateactual))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! I did what you suggested but deleted the first "CONVERT" and it worked :)