# Can I use "/" operator on nvarchar column type in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, operators, ssms, nvarchar

I am trying to divide 2 columns which are defined as `nvarchar`, but SSMS throws an error saying you can not use `/` operator on `nvarchar`.

```
select 
    location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, 
    (total_deaths / total_cases) * 100
from 
    CovidDeaths#xlsx$
order by 
    1, 2
```

I am unable to divide the `total_cases` and `total_deaths`.

Comment: Of course you can't divide two text values. You might just as well try to divide "foo" / "bar". But you could try `cast()`-ing the values to some numeric type first.

Comment: Also, telling us you use Management Studio is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dashboard radio. Fine some of the time, but less helpful when talking to your mechanic about engine trouble.

Comment: This is literally the 3rd time I have seen this question in less than 24 hours... [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75782146/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75790206/2029983), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75794352/2029983)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operand data type varchar is invalid for divide operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155682/operand-data-type-varchar-is-invalid-for-divide-operator)

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Store numbers as numbers, and forget about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead since you cannot divide "string" values. Consider converting or casting to a decimal value. I'm assuming total_cases is nonzero in my answer.

```
select 
    location, 
    date, 
    total_cases, 
    total_deaths, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_deaths) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_cases))) as [DeathsOverTotal]
from CovidDeaths#xlsx$
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Select location, date, total_cases,total_deaths, 

(CONVERT(float, total_deaths) / NULLIF(CONVERT(float, total_cases), 0)) * 100 AS Deathpercentage

from PortfolioProject..covidDeaths

order by 1,2